# Having a TypeError: SearchAlgorithms.breadthFirstSearch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'graph'

Tags: python

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
from pprint import pprint

graph = {
         "San Bernardino": ["Riverside", "Rancho Cucamonga"], 
         "Riverside": ["San Bernardino", "Ontario", "Pomona"],
         "Rancho Cucamonga": ["San Bernardino", "Azusa", "Los Angeles"],
         "Ontario": ["Riverside", "Whittier", "Los Angeles"],
         "Pomona": ["Riverside", "Whittier", "Azusa", "Los Angeles"], 
         "Whittier": ["Ontario", "Pomona", "Los Angeles"],
         "Azusa": ["Rancho Cucamonga", "Pomona", "Arcadia"], 
         "Arcadia": ["Azusa", "Los Angeles"],
         "Los Angeles": ["Rancho Cucamonga", "Ontario", "Pomona", "Whittier", "Arcadia"]
        }

weights = {('San Bernardino', 'Riverside'): 2,
 ('San Bernardino', 'Rancho Cucamonga'): 1,
 ('Riverside', 'Ontario'): 1,
 ('Riverside', 'Pomona'): 3,
 ('Rancho Cucamonga', 'Los Angeles'): 5,
 ('Pomona', 'Los Angeles'): 2,
 ('Ontario', 'Whittier'): 2,
 ('Ontario', 'Los Angeles'): 3,
 ('Rancho Cucamonga', 'Azusa'): 3,
 ('Pomona', 'Azusa'): 2,
 ('Pomona', 'Whittier'): 2,
 ('Azusa', 'Arcadia'): 1,
 ('Whittier', 'Los Angeles'): 2,
 ('Arcadia', 'Los Angeles'): 2}



heuristic = {'San Bernardino': 4,
 'Riverside': 2,
 'Rancho Cucamonga': 1,
 'Ontario': 1,
 'Pomona': 3,
 'Whittier': 4,
 'Azusa': 3,
 'Arcadia': 2,
 'Los Angeles': 0}

class SearchAlgorithms:
    def breadthFirstSearch(self, start, stack, goal, graph):
        while stack:
             current = stack.pop()
             if current == goal:
                  path.append(current)
                  return path, visited
             if current not in visited:
                  visited.add(current)
                  path.append(current)
                  for neighbor in reversed(graph[current]):
                       if neighbor not in visited:
                            stack.append(neighbor)
        return {"Returned solution: [], Expanded cities: {}".format(explored)}

# Call to create the object of the above class

search = SearchAlgorithms() 

# Call to each algorithm to print the results

print("Breadth First Search Result") # ['San Bernardino', 'Rancho Cucamonga', 'Los Angeles'] pprint(search.breadthFirstSearch('San Bernardino', 'Los Angeles', graph))
```

I tried running the the code I have, however I get that error.

Comment: You only supply 3 arguments here. `search.breadthFirstSearch('San Bernardino', 'Los Angeles', graph)` Your method takes 4 (excluding `self`). `def breadthFirstSearch(self, start, stack, goal, graph)`

Comment: Oh I see. But before I added stack to def breadthFirstSearch(self, start, stack, goal, graph) due to another error saying stack not being defined.

Comment: ive also changed my def breadthFirstSearch(self, start, stack, goal, graph) to just def breadthFirstSearch(self, stack, goal, graph). I get the  current = stack.pop()
                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'